# Listing all post from different custom post type for the logged in user

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to show in a list page all the post that the current logged in user could have created in differents custom post type (5)

For exemple : the user makes a new post using a form using new_post.php and it's added in the WP custom-post-type 'Cookies' if it's what he selected from a dropdown list.

Then the user want to see his post so i'd list him all the post he made no matter what custom-post-type he posted to.

Thks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2):

Try Below code.This will helpful

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$args = array(
'author' => $user_id 
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

  // Do Stuff
endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Thks! I'll give it a try